# Reindexing pandas dataframe for stacking with new unique index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-analysis

I have several dataframes which look like the following:

```
In [2]: skew
Out[2]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 96 entries, 2006-01-31 00:00:00 to 2013-12-31 00:00:00
Freq: BM
Data columns (total 3 columns):
AAPL    96  non-null values
GOOG    96  non-null values
MSFT    96  non-null values
dtypes: float64(3)

In [3]: skew.head()
Out[3]: 
                AAPL      GOOG      MSFT
2006-01-31  0.531769 -0.567731  2.132850
2006-02-28 -0.389711  0.028723  0.724277
2006-03-31  1.184884  1.009587 -0.959136
2006-04-28  1.664745  0.852869 -4.020731
2006-05-31 -0.419757 -0.288422  0.240444

In [5]: skew.index
Out[5]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2006-01-31 00:00:00, ..., 2013-12-31 00:00:00]
Length: 96, Freq: BM, Timezone: None
```

I want to generate a single column of them with a unique index so that I can merge it with the columns from the other dataframes at a later point, which would looks somewhat like this, but with an unique index:

```
frame
Out[6]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 288 entries, 2006-01-31 00:00:00 to 2013-12-31 00:00:00
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Returns    285  non-null values
Skew       288  non-null values
WinLose    288  non-null values
dtypes: bool(1), float64(2)

In [7]: frame.head()
Out[7]: 
             Returns      Skew WinLose
2006-01-31       NaN  0.531769    True
2006-02-28 -0.092968 -0.389711   False
2006-03-31 -0.084246  1.184884    True
2006-04-28  0.122290  1.664745   False
2006-05-31 -0.150874 -0.419757   False
```

i.e, something like:

```
In [7]: frame.head()
Out[7]: 
                     Returns      Skew WinLose
2006-01-31-AAPL          NaN  0.531769    True
2006-02-28-MSFT    -0.092968 -0.389711   False
2006-03-31-AAPL    -0.084246  1.184884    True
2006-04-28-GOGL     0.122290  1.664745   False
2006-05-31-AAPL    -0.150874 -0.419757   False
```

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd 
import pandas.io.data as web



#Class parameters
names = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT']

# Functions
def get_px(stock, start, end):
    return web.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)['Close']

def getWinnerLoser(stock, medRet, retsM):
    return retsM[stock].shift(-1) >= medRet.shift(-1)

def getSkew( stock, rets, period):
return pd.rolling_skew(rets[stock],period).asfreq('BM').fillna(method='pad')

px = pd.DataFrame(data={n: get_px(n,'1/1/2006','1/1/2014') for n in names})
px = px.asfreq('B').fillna(method = 'pad')
rets = px.pct_change()

# Monthly returns and median return
retsM = px.asfreq('BM').fillna(method = 'pad').pct_change()
medRet = retsM.median(axis = 1)

# Dataframes
winLose = pd.DataFrame(data = {n: getWinnerLoser(n,medRet,retsM) for n in names})
skew = pd.DataFrame(data = {n: getSkew(n,rets,20) for n in names})

# Concatenating
retsMCon = pd.concat(retsM[n] for n in names)
winLoseCon = pd.concat(winLose[n] for n in names)
skewCon = pd.concat(skew[n] for n in names)

frame = pd.DataFrame({'Returns':retsMCon, 'Skew':skewCon, 'WinLose':winLoseCon})
```

I have yet to find a good solution to this

Comment: some kind of join? Not clear what you're after.

Comment: Do you want to stack AAPL/GOOG/MSFT on top of each other in one column, add the 'Returns' & 'WinLose' columns, and then add another column 'unique_id' (or something similar) ?

Comment: Sorry for my lacking explanation. If you look at the data frame 'frame', that is what I want. But I want to stack e.g. the skew metric for all the stocks on top of each other but with a unique index so that in frame it can be joined with the other metrics calculated from the same period.

So I calculate different metrics for different stocks, but at the end I want them all aggregated in a frame like 'frame', but it has to be so that e.g. skew and return correspond to the same 'date' and the same stock from the original indexing and frame (i.e. 'Skew', 'Returns').